# I need to find in which subject the student has scored the highest marks in matillion

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

I need to find in  which subject the student has scored the most marks(only the subject name is enough) using matillion
My data looks like this

```
studentid   maths   science art computer sports
1             55     68      59   75     62
2             75     68      79   56     89
3             89     85      74   32     56
4             89     92      86   75     12
5             99     100     45  68      45
```

And I want my result to look like this

```
studentid     highestmark
1              computer
2              sports
3              maths
4              science                     
5              science
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added to Gordon's answer to get highest mark too.

select t.*,
(case greatest(maths, science, art, computer, sports)
when maths then 'maths'
when science then 'science'
when art then 'art'
when computer then 'computer'
when sports then 'sports'
end) as highestmark,

greatest(maths, science, art, computer, sports) highest_mark
from t;

Comment: can u please help me with another question too i've attached the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291812/how-to-add-a-constant-value-1-in-an-empty-column-in-snowflake-matillion

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, or most SQL dialects, you can use `greatest()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case greatest(maths, science, art, computer, sports)
           when maths then 'maths'
           when science then 'science'
           when art then 'art'
           when computer then 'computer'
           when sports then 'sports'
        end) as highestmark
from t;
```

Comment: sorry @gordonlinoff i also need to display the mark in that subject                                                         it should look like                                  1  maths 99

Comment: @Gowtham_7 . . . That is not the question you asked here, but you can just use the `greatest()` function.