# how to add a constant value (1) in an empty column in snowflake-matillion

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

my table looks like

```
id  total  avg  test_no
1   445     89 
2   434     85
3   378     75
4   421     84
```

I'm working on matillion-snowflake

I need my result to look like

```
id  total  avg  test_no
1   445     89   1
2   434     85   1
3   378     75   1
4   421     84   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Calculator component and set the value of the calculated column to 1

Comment: I can't find the calculated column in the calculator component @NickW

Comment: Read the "Calculator and Join components" section here: https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2037694. Also, can I suggest that if you are going to use Matillion then you run through the Guides/Course here: https://academy.matillion.com/ so that you have a solid understanding of how the product works

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, you would modify the table using:

```
update t
    set test_no = 1;
```

I assume that Matillion supports this as well.

Comment: I don't see a function named SET in the calculator component in matillion @gordonlinoff

Comment: can you explain how I can do it in matillion?@gordonlinoff